# tomcat7 hangs up 100%cpu and restart tomcat be of no effect . until restart system

Tags: java, linux, tomcat7, restart, freeze

my server runs on centos 6.5

i can't unstand why restart the tomcat, the problem can't fix. until restart os is ok. please some can help me? below is my  envronment: thanks!

running env is:

Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.55

Server built:   Jul 18 2014 05:34:04

Server number:  7.0.55.0

OS Name:        Linux

OS Version:     2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64

Architecture:   amd64

JVM Version:    1.7.0_67-b01

JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xmx12g -XX:NewRatio=4 -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=68 -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails  -Xloggc:$CATALINA_BASE/logs/tomcat_gc.log -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager"
```

jstack:  i dumped 4 thread stack using jstack on 4 diffrent time
[4 jstack file](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1jGKMxDW#path=%252Fjstack)

Comment: Is there any application running on Tomcat ? maybe you should look at them

Comment: yes . its a game server.  online number is few.  current load is 4-7;   after restart os and tomcat . the load is (0-1]

Answer (score 0):

Please check -Xmx12g parameter for JAVA_OPTS. Make sure you do have 12 GB memory available.

[Not able to add as comment hence adding as answer]